# Best Authenticiation method to connect External Apps to Woocommerce

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

I am looking to connect my WordPress woo commerce login to an external app's authentication.

1. android app.
2. asp.net MVC application.

The User will be generating a username and password when creating an account with the woo-commerce checkout by buying a subscription. Using that username and password he should have to log in securely in both the asp.net MVC application and the android app. A single sign-on for all three states (woocommerce,asp.net MVC application and android app)

I thought it is possible via REST API, but woocommerce allows only cookie-based authentication. so the password cannot be used on the other apps.

Can anyone please suggest, any best secure option to do this?